# Is there a way to avoid re-render continuously when calling a WebSocket from React component?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, rerender

I have a stuck with avoiding component re-render when I use a Websocket for receiving data and update them to UI. I have a component named A and I use a Websocket into it for receiving a real-time message and then show it to UI. I use "useEffect" hook like that:

```
function User() {
  let ws = new Websocket(host);
  let [users, setUser] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
   let message = [];
   ws.onmessage = evt => {
     message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
     setUser(message);
   }}, [users]);
 
 return (
    <div className="user-table">
      <Table users={users} />
    </div>
   )
}
```

Because the Websocket frequently has the new data (1 second), it causes the component always update. So, is there any way for avoiding this problem? (caching or something like that)

Comment: You do `setUser` - can you show how `user` is used? Does it get rendered somewhere?

Comment: I declare it by using the react hook. Like that:  let [users, setUser] = useState([]). Sorry for missing it in the post.

Comment: Yep, it's clear that it's a hook, but where is it *used*? Can you show how the component renders?

Comment: I dont really understand what is the problem here. The reason why u using sockets is that probably u need real time data and if you want to avoid getting data that frequently then why u even using websockets at all. Just use plain ajax request whenever u need new data.
Also, if one time render  is enough for you then you can change ` [users]` to `[]`

Comment: Hi harry, I'm using the socket because I would like to sure that I don't miss any new data and I want the UI to update automatically whenever the server has new data.

Comment: Hi  CertainPerformance , as you can see in my "useEffect" hook I have an "ws.onmessage" function. It responsible for listening and getting data from socket. If there any new data, it will receive data and make a setState and then the component will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the socket in itself, but the fact that your `useEffect` dependency array contains a state, and that the `useEffect` callback adds a listener, and that the callback changes the state. Every time `setUser` is called, `users` changes - and when `users` changes, the `useEffect` runs again, because one of its dependencies changed.

Remove `users` from the dependency array, and only declare the socket *once*, in the `useEffect` so that you only have one socket (per `User`, at least...) active at a time.

```
function User() {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new Websocket(host);
    ws.onmessage = evt => {
      setUsers(JSON.parse(evt.data));
    };
    // Close socket on unmount:
    return () => ws.close();
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency array; only run callback once, on mount
 
  return (
    <div className="user-table">
      <Table users={users} />
    </div>
   );
}
```

Also note:

- Best to [prefer `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) over `let` in ES6
- To reduce bugs, name variables appropriately - if you have multiple users, use `users` and `setUsers`. (If you have only a single user, use `user` and `setUser`)

If there's any chance of there being more than one `User`, it would be better to create the socket just once *in the parent*, then pass it down as a prop; that way, you won't be creating multiple sockets which all do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I realize my problem is the socket always sends the data about 1-second once.